# CMake link files from subdirectories and parent directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a folder net like:

```
main
   headers
      cls1.hpp   cls2.hpp ...
   sources
      cls1.cpp   cls2.cpp ...
resources
   r1.hpp   r2.hpp ...
```

I have tried more cmake methods to link the files, like

```
set(SRC ${SRC})
```

in parent dir and

```
set(SRC ${SRC} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/cls1.cpp PARENT_SCOPE)
```

in subdir

OR

```
file(GLOB_RECURSE SRC_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp)
file(GLOB_RECURSE HDR_FILES ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.hpp)
```

to get the .cpp and .hpp files, but when I do

```
#include "resources/r1.hpp"
```

I get error like `"resources/r1.hpp" No such a file or directory`

Can anyone help me pleas? How can I do linking between files in folders in my case?

Comment: Why are you using `res/cls1.hpp`? Shouldn't you use `headers/cls1.hpp`?

Comment: Sorry, it was `r1.hpp`, but why do I get that error?

Comment: I think it should be `resources/r1.hpp` and not `res/r1.hpp`. Still, when you include a file within another, its path is relative to the current file.
Thus you should write something like `#include ../../resources/r1.hpp`.

Comment: come on! you understand what I mean! I know how to write an include. I am searching for solutions, and I was writing it in a hurry, sorry, I think now it is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve this specific problem, in your main CMakeLists.txt add this line before adding subfolders:

```
include_directories(".")
```

This will allow the compiler to see the file located in `resources/r1.hpp` starting from the root path.

However, I suggest you take a look to some CMake projects examples, because it doesn't seem you are doing things in the standard way (e.g. usually a good way is to add a sub directory that creates its own library, that then you link to your main executable)

Comment: Thanks, This was it!!! I was getting desperate. I have not enough rep to vote up your answer, sorry.